# How can I accept a C# ObjectResult or an Object in an Angular API

Tags: c#, angular, http-status-codes

I'm trying to send error messages from C# to an Angular API by using the `StatusCode()` method. How can I write something in Angular that handles the StatusCode response, AND the correct data?

My angular code (which handles the correct data, but not the StatusCode):

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

isUniqueEmailPhone(userid='',emailphone: string): Observable<Myclass[]> {
    return this.http.get('/api/me/isUniqueEmailPhone', {
        params: new HttpParams()
            .set('userid', userid)
            .set('emailphone', emailphone)
    })}
```

c# API returns: `StatusCode(500,"Error xyz")` Everything breaks

c# API returns `new List<Myclass>()` Everything works fine

Comment: are you adding error subscribtion  handler `isUniqueEmailPhone(...).subscrbe(successHandler, errorHandler, completeHandler)`?

Comment: @Xesenix no, but error subscription handlers sound like the kind of thing I should be doing. Is that how you recommend handling this?

Comment: probably but im not sure if your server response will automatically be routed to error handler or there is somewhere middle step (interceptor) which handles your server responses that would be other place to check if error subscription wouldnt work https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

Answer (score 0):

I wound up adding a catch error pipe to the Observable like this:

```
isUniqueEmailPhone(userid='',emailphone: string): Observable<Myclass[]> {
return this.http.get<CardType[]>('/api/me/isUniqueEmailPhone')
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError<CardType[]>('getAllCardTypes')));
```

This calls the handle error method which I copied from [here](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/error-handling-with-angular-6-tips-and-best-practices192) and modified. This method now returns an empty object of the type (in this case `CardType[]`) which is returned to allow everything to continue after logging the error:

```
private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
        let res = "Service error: " + `${operation} failed\n`
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) { //add more data if this is HttpErrorResponse type
            res += 'Msg: '+error.message + '<br>Status: ' + error.status + '<br>Detail: ' + error.error + '<br>Text: ' + error.statusText + '<br>Object: ' + JSON.stringify(result)
        }
        alert(res);
        // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
        return of(result as T);
    };
}
```